# How to know programmatically if Smartpad Emergency stop is pressed?

Tags: kuka-krl

I have a machine with a lot of emergency buttons and for each one I have a signal to the PLC saying it is pressed. So I know which button is pressed.
I also have a KRC4 on the security and I do not have any signal from it to the PLC saying that it's emergency is pressed.
I could go by elimination, if none was pressed, so the robot is. But is not the best option because maybe I just have wire from the buttons disconnected and I will assume that is the robot that is in emergency.

I was thinking about getting a system variable that says it is pressed, but I could not find one. Does someone know how to know if the emergency is pressed programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

maybe this helps:

The following predefined data lists exist in the KR C...:

`$MACHINE.DAT`
is a predefined data list with exclusively predefined system variables. The machine data
serve the purpose of adapting the controller to the connected robot (kinematic
information, control parameters, etc.). There is a `$MACHINE.DAT` in both the control
system and the robot system. You cannot create new variables or delete existing ones.

Examples:

`$ALARM_STOP` Signal for Emergency Stop (controller--specific)

Answer (score 1):

Select (assuming that you have 'English' as selected language) Display-> Input/Outputs->External Automatic. This will open up a window where you can connect almost any event or state in the controller to one of the outputs that you have mapped to your PLC. The events or states are more or less self explanatory. Select one and press Configure and Edit to change the output from a default value to the one you desire.

There is no need for a restart afterwards. Just close the wizard and you are good to go. This is also where you can set up inputs for a remote start of the robot. Post a question if you need more details on this topic. Good luck!